# How to check for existed fields in fields or localstorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

when user clicks on UPDATE button, I want to inform him to need to change some fields if want to update items or in other solution to do this update function.

```
update() {
    this.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled()
      .then((isEnabled) => {
        if (isEnabled) {

          let warrents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('__mydb/_ionickv/DodNalog'));
          for (let i = 0; i < warrents.length; i++) {
            if (warrents[i].id === this.WarrentItem.id) {
              warrents[i] = this.WarrentItem;
              break;
            }

          }
          console.log("Item after update ", warrents);
          this.dialogSaved();
          this.storage.set('DodNalog', warrents);
        }

        else {
          this.neradiGps();
          console.log('ne radi gps');
        }

      });
  }
```

Comment: What is `this.storage`?

Answer (score 1):

**To check for the field in localStorage use**

```
localStorage.getItem('nameofthevariable'); and compare with NULL
```

**To set the value use-**

```
localStorage.setItem('nameoffield',value);
```